# Is the Travelodge chain in the UK part of any loyalty programme?

Tags: uk, hotels, loyalty-programs

I know that the Travelodge chain of hotels in some regions of the world is part of the [Wyndham Rewards](https://www.wyndhamrewards.com/) programme. However, I'm not quite sure whether the UK chain (it [doesn't seem to be affiliated with the main brand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelodge_UK)) is part of any loyalty programme. Is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't part of any of the big hotel chains. That's partly why it's so cheap. That means no credit to any loyalty programs you might be a member of, sorry.

Travelodge UK doesn't have its own loyalty program either. All they have is [business discounts and billing](https://www.travelodge.co.uk/business/index.php).